# AutoResetEvent triggers itself

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, autoresetevent

i've got a weird behavior of AutoResetEvent

there is the code in Utils class:

```
class Utils
{
    public static AutoResetEvent FileDownloaded = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public static void DownloadFileAsync(string sourceUrl, string toPath)
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var url = new Uri(sourceUrl); 
        FileDownloaded.Reset();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DownloadStringAsinc completed");
            if(e.Error != null || string.IsNullOrEmpty( e.Result))
            {
                               //do retries
            }
            else
            {
                FileDownloaded.Set();
            }
        };
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(url);
    }
}
```

and there is the code when it is listened to:

```
public DoSomeWork()
{
    Utils.DownloadFileAsync(iniUrl, localIni);
    if(Utils.FileDownloaded.WaitOne(2222))
    {
     //....
    }
    else
    //it goes here at initial run
}
```

it called like this:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

bw.DoWork += (object o, DoWorkEventArgs args) =>
     {
            DoSomeWork();
     }   
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

in this case, first time when WaitOne is called, it returns false right away (like it was timed out). second time is ok
there is even no "DownloadStringAsinc completed" in debug output.
when i was calling Utils.FileDownloaded.WaitOne(2222) from main thread (i know it isn't right, was just testing) it worked like it is supposed to. but when i moved block to thread, this behavior appeared.
also, if i make Thread.Sleep(200) before the "if" statement in later block, everything works fine

must add: code from Utils class is not called simultaneously from different places.

i may consider like: "ok the problem is solved for this application". but it is not solved for my head. i must understand.

Comment: what block did you move to what thread again? Could you make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead of the code you posted?

Comment: second block and hence the whole thing is in separate thread now

Comment: You didn't do anything obvious to *cancel* the download when you WaitOne() returned false.  So second time through the code, you've now got **two** WebClient instances that both use the same ARE.

Comment: it is not necessary to call it second time.. what i was telling, is: after execution of given code, the event is triggered right away as it was timed out (WaitOne returns false = timed out)